# Yii2: Why Query Builder not return same result as SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, yii2, query-builder

**[UPDATED] Fixed**

I have an *SQL statement* like this

```
SELECT
    jea.subemployer_id,
    jea.employer_id,
    jea.job_id 
FROM
    job_employer_assoc AS jea
    INNER JOIN job AS j ON jea.job_id = j.job_id
    INNER JOIN subemployer AS s ON jea.subemployer_id = s.subemployer_id 
WHERE
    j.deleted = 0 
    AND j.klq = 0 
    AND j.STATUS = 0 
    AND s.FUNCTION IN ( 0, 1 ) 
GROUP BY
    job_id
```

And this is my **Query Builder**:

```
public function getAllValidEmployerID()
    {
        $resultQuery = (new Query())
            ->select(['jea.subemployer_id', 'jea.employer_id', 'jea.job_id'])
            ->from(['job_employer_assoc AS jea'])
            ->innerJoin('job AS j', ['jea.job_id' => 'j.job_id'])
            ->innerJoin('subemployer AS s', ['jea.subemployer_id' => 's.subemployer_id'])
            ->where(['j.deleted' => 0])
            ->andWhere(['j.klq' => 0])
            ->andWhere(['j.status' => 0])
            ->andWhere(['s.function' => [0, 1]])
            ->groupBy('job_id')
            ->all();
        return $resultQuery;
    }
```

Why the ***SQL statement returns values*** while ***Query Builder returns an empty array***?

Comment: I finally find out why, ['jea.job_id' => 'j.job_id'] should be 'jea.job_id = j.job_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find out why, `['jea.job_id' => 'j.job_id']` should be `'jea.job_id = j.job_id'`